# Winform TextBox HideSelection and GotFocus

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Can anyone can tell me why the two following codes have different behaviour? The first code will call the Textbox `GotFocus` event while the second code won't call the `GotFocus` event after `lostfocus` is executed. For your information, `HideSelection` is set to false initially to highlight all the text box at the first time.

```
private void textBox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TextBox item in this.textbox)  //got 3 text box,
    {
        if (item.Focused == true)
        {
             item.HideSelection = false;
             item.SelectAll();
        }
        else
             item.HideSelection = true;
}
```

and

```
private void textBox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TextBox item in this.textbox)  //got 3 text box,
    {                     
        if (item.Focused == true)
        {
            item.HideSelection = true;   //difference here
            item.HideSelection = false;
            item.SelectAll();
        }
        else
            item.HideSelection = true;
}
```